# How to fix deadlock with help of condition variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to implement the following case

1. Input - integer number `n`
2. Start 3 threads. The first thread prints 'a', the second prints 'b', the third prints 'c', then the first thread prints 'a' and so on

**Example**: Input - 6, Output - "abcabc"

I want to use condition variable to synchronise threads

My code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>

void print(
    std::mutex& mutex, 
    std::condition_variable& to_wait, 
    std::condition_variable& to_notify, 
    int count,
    char ch)
{
    std::unique_lock lock(mutex);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        to_wait.wait(lock);
        std::cout << ch;
        to_notify.notify_all();
    }
};


int main()
{
    const int count = 10;

    std::condition_variable var_a;
    std::condition_variable var_b;
    std::condition_variable var_c;
    std::mutex mutex;

    auto thread_a = std::thread(&print, std::ref(mutex), std::ref(var_a), std::ref(var_b), count, 'a');
    auto thread_b = std::thread(&print, std::ref(mutex), std::ref(var_b), std::ref(var_c), count, 'b');
    auto thread_c = std::thread(&print, std::ref(mutex), std::ref(var_c), std::ref(var_a), count, 'c');

    var_a.notify_one();

    thread_a.join();
    thread_b.join();
    thread_c.join();

    return 0;
}
```

**Problem** - sometimes code prints correct output, but sometimes I have no outout (suppose deadlock)

Comment: condition variables are NOT variables they are more like a kind of signal. For each condition variable you would also need an extra variable, and when waiting for a condition variable you ALWAYS need to wait with a predicate. (condition variables can spuriously wake up even if the condition you are waiting for is not true yet). Look at the link to the example I send in your previous question.

Comment: Your initial setup is prone to race conditions: if `thread_a` is not at the `to_wait.wait(lock)` statement when you call `var_a.notify_one()` from the main thread, nothing will happen. Similarly for the other threads.

Comment: Semaphores are more appropriate for this.

Comment: **Q:** Homework? If it's homework, then do what the assignment requires. But also be aware that the assignment is B\*\*\*S\*\*\*. The _\*only\*_ reason for using threads, ever, is you want two or more threads to do different things at the same time. But, the assignment requires threads to strictly take turns. It requires that no two threads are _ever_ allowed to do anything interesting at the same time. The assignment will teach you something about _how_ to coordinate the activity of different threads, but it's sending completely the wrong message about _when_ or _why_ to coordinate them.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using condition variables the way they are meant to be used. The are not a signalling system, but a way to let threads know that a condition was changed and you're not using a condition. The data in the condition is shared and should be locked by the mutex when changing and checking.

The best way to avoid this is to always [`std::condition_variable::wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) with predicate where the condition is passed as a parameter.

In this case, you're just serializing, so the condition can be a counter and only one cv is needed.

Comment: Thank you, could you please advice how to fix code?

Comment: @mascai I did advice: use a counter and check the condition in a function you pass to `wait_for`. So for starting the thread, pass the parameters mutex, 1 cv, counter variable, number of threads and number of loops. In the condition, also check the number of loops to finish the thread. I added a link to the wait_for page for an example.

Comment: Oops, it's been a while. You don't need the wait_for, you need the wait with predicate. I'm changing my answer.